# SQL Query with JOIN, WHERE and AND clause to convert in Laravel queries

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm having problem converting my SQL query to laravel queries. I want to join two tables `users` and `messages` so that i can get the users that has conversation with other users.

Database Structure:

Users:
[image]

Messages:

[image]

This is my SQL query where I get what I want:

[image]

```
SELECT u.id, c.id, u.first_name, u.last_name FROM messages c, users u 
      WHERE (CASE WHEN c.user_one =  @USERID THEN c.user_two = u.ID WHEN c.user_two = @USERID THEN c.user_one= u.id END ) 
      AND ( c.user_one = @USERID OR c.user_two = @USERID ) Order by c.id DESC Limit 20
```

This is my Laravel query:

```
DB::table('messages')
   ->join('users', function($join) use ($user_id) {
        $join->select(DB::raw('CASE WHEN messages.user_one = ' . $user_id . ' THEN messages.user_two = ' . $user_id . 'WHEN messages.user_two = ' . $user_id . ' THEN messages.user_one = ' . $user_id));
        $join->on(function($query) use ($user_id)
        {
             $query->where('messages.user_one', '=', $user_id);
             $query->orWhere('messages.user_two', '=',$user_id);
        });       
   })
   ->select('users.*', 'messages.*')
   ->get();
```

Comment: Where is @userid defined?

Comment: What does "the users that has conversation with other users" mean? You want all users which are in messages table in column user_one or user_two?

Comment: @Strawberry it is being pass as a parameter, `function getMessage($user_id)`

@Autista_z in other terms i just want to display all conversation of the current user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Sorry my original answer was not injecting variables in a secure way. Please use this for securely injecting variables in raw queries.

**SQL injection security in raw statements.**

> In raw queries we need remember to pass all variables to our mysql
> database using provided second argument.
>
> In your case, you just place question marks placeholders, where you want to have your variables injected and then put your variables in same order as your placeholders in your second argument array.

Source: http://s4.jeffsbio.co.uk/laravel-5-query-builder-where-raw-2

**Updated Query:-**

```
DB::table('messages as m')
        ->join('users as u',function($join){
            $join->on('u.id','=','m.user_one')
            ->orOn('u.id','=','m.user_two'); 
        })
        ->where(function($query) use($user_id){
            $query->where('m.user_one','=',$user_id);
            $query->orWhere('m.user_two','=',$user_id);
        })
       ->where(function($query) use($user_id){
            $query->whereRaw(
                        'CASE WHEN m.user_one = ?'.
                        ' THEN m.user_two = u.id'. 
                        ' WHEN m.user_two = ?'.
                        ' THEN m.user_one = u.id END',[$user_id,$user_id]);
                    //here we passed the variables in exact order of their usage in query
       })
      ->select('u.id as user_id', 'm.id as messages_id','u.first_name','u.last_name')
      ->orderBy('m.id','DESC')
      ->limit('20')
      ->get(
```

**Original Answer:**
You can't use `select` clause in `join` clause like you have.

Use this :-

```
DB::table('messages as m')
->join('users as u',function($join){
     $join->on('u.id','=','m.user_one')
     ->orOn('u.id','=','m.user_two'); 
})
->where(function($query) use($user_id){
    $query->where('m.user_one','=',$user_id);
    $query->orWhere('m.user_two','=',$user_id);
})
->where(function($query) use($user_id){
    $query->whereRaw(DB::raw(
           'CASE WHEN m.user_one = '.$user_id.
           ' THEN m.user_two = u.id'. 
           ' WHEN m.user_two = '.$user_id.
           ' THEN m.user_one = u.id END'));
   })
->select('u.id as user_id', 'm.id as messages_id','u.first_name','u.last_name')
 ->orderBy('m.id','DESC')
 ->limit('20')
 ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works. Im just curious about injection points while using `DB::raw`, it is safe to inject the user_id that way?

Comment: @JAlc Thanks for pointing out your opinion, I was not injecting the variables in a secure way. I have updated my answer, please have a look.

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  :)